# Java code to convert SVG to PNG with UTF-8 character

Tags: java, tomcat, svg, png, batik

I am using below code to create PNG from SVG file and write it to Servlet output stream. The SVG file is having UTF-8(Japanese) characters in AXIS name.

> ```
> ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
> InputStream svgFileStream = new FileInputStream(svgFile);
> TranscoderInput inputSvgImage = new TranscoderInput(svgFileStream);
> PNGTranscoder converter = new PNGTranscoder();
> TranscoderOutput outputPngImage = new TranscoderOutput(out);
> converter.transcode(inputSvgImage, outputPngImage);
> ```

The above code is working fine in my local but when I upload it to the server it shows squares instead of character. When there is English character instead of Japanese it works fine on both local as well as server.

Can you please let me know if you have faced same issue. 
Can it be related to Tomcat ?

I have checked SVG file from server, UTF-8 characters are visible in it.
I also tried InputStreamReader instead of InputStream with "UTF-8" but did not work.

As per one response found I tried Write instead of ServletOutputStream with "UTF-8" in TranscoderOutput but it did not create any image.

Thanks

Comment: If you have control over the Tomcat server you are running on, you can try to specify the following JVM option:   -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Comment: Some Java classes by default use a system-wide ("platform") "default" charset that is based on locale and system configuration. That's why your code may perform differently in different environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### UPDATE

As far as it is working correctly on your local and you serve a png image as a result, it has to be independent from application server's encoding configuration, and your svg file itself is correctly encoded I do not think it is an encoding issue.

@Eugene K. yes there is a possibility that some java classes uses the os default locale implicitly but I can not reproduce the problem with the same code given in question although I do not have Japanese locale.
IMHO it is highly probable that server has some missing fonts installed.

It may not be an elegant way and also does not related with Java but as a solution if you have a chance to edit your source svg file somehow which it can also be dynamically with some string manipulation if you ever need, you can provide a font which includes Japanese characters and serve it from your servlet. Then add these to your svg file and specify a font family for your text:

```
<defs>
  <style type="text/css">
  <![CDATA[
  @font-face {
    font-family: Somefont;
    src: url('http://localhost:8080/Somefont.ttf');
  }
  ]]>
  </style>
</defs>
<text font-family="Somefont" font-size="40" fill="blue">Text for test!</text>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks It worked... But in batik library it not showing hard line for X and Y axis in PNG file. Is there a way to show it ?

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad that it worked for you :) Actually I am not familiar with batik library in detail. I think you generate or manipulate svg with batik in order to create a graph or chart, right? If so if you can provide a little more detail about what these hard line for X and Y axis exactly I will try to help. Also if you have any chance to share the content of svg file it will be much better

Comment: Hi, I have created another post   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54265111/svg-file-converted-to-png-using-batik-but-no-axis-line